# Sharepoint not sending mail using alternate access mapping path

Tags: 2013, web-application, alternate-access-mapping, load-balancing

I am using load balancer (WFE1 + WFE2) and my web application is configured as `http://server` which I defined in host header. I have also added AAM `http://realsite`. So when a user types AAM in URL then the website loads. It is working fine without issues. The only issue is when ever SharePoint sends email (for e.g. if workflow starts or ends, or when some one sets up alert on list etc.) then in email it sends URL `http://server` instead of `http://realsite`

Even though using `http://server` also opens the site but I want it to send email using `http://realsite`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can recall, email is sent with links from the Default zone.

Check your different zones to ensure the settings all line up.

Hope this helps.